# Android Custom ListView has no items

Tags: android, listview

I tried to set up a custom ListView as a table to display Product Details. As you see in my Code I use a custom adapter and a additional xml file to populate the ListView. My problem is that the ListView ist empty. There are no items displayed and I do not see my mistake. Can you help me?

Fragment:

```
public class ProductDetail1Fragment extends Fragment {

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_product_detail1,container,false);

    HashMap<String,String> mapProduct = new HashMap<String,String>();

    for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
        mapProduct.put("Key" + i, "Value" + i);
    }

    ListView listView=(ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.productListview);
    ProductDetailAdapter adapter = new ProductDetailAdapter(getActivity(),mapProduct);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    return view;


}
```

Adapter:

```
public class ProductDetailAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private HashMap<String,String> list;
    private Context context;

public ProductDetailAdapter(Context c, HashMap<String,String> list){
    super();
    this.context = c;
    this.list=list;

}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    if(convertView == null){
        convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.product_detail_data_row,null);
    }
    TextView textViewKey = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.productDataKey);
    TextView textViewValue = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.productDataValue);


    textViewKey.setText("tst");
    textViewValue.setText("ddfadfs");

    return convertView;
}
}
```

Fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.parker.tfdeapp.ProductDetail2Fragment">

<ListView
android:id="@+id/productListview"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Listview_row.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/productDataKey"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/productDataValue"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: this code should not even compile as `ProductDetailAdapter` is not  implementing `BaseAdapter` abstract class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Need to change ListView to match parent height (its bad performance):

```
 <ListView
    android:id="@+id/productListview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

2) Just to override missing functions in your BaseAdapte:

```
@Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public ListData getItem(int index) {
        return mList.get(index);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int index) {
        return index;
    }
```

3) Use [ViewHolder](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html)... its very good pattern

Answer (score 2):

Add getCount method in your adapter

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return list.size();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add this Override methods in your adapter class

```
 @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public ListData getItem(int position) {
        return list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Missing  class implementations of `BaseAdapter`.
See the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html)

```
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public ListData getItem(int position) {
        return list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
```

> Implementing `getCount()` only makes items visible. Because it provides
>   item counts.